# How to make call records to show up on the web page (Asterisk CDR)?

Tags: cdr

We use Asterisk CDR and everything works fine, but the web page (Apache) shows call records for today only. So, yesterday there were only yesterday's calls, today there are only today's calls, etc.
Physically the call records are in the folder where trey're supposed to be, but for some reason we can't see them on the web page.
Almost everything is by default here and we even are sure it worked as needed before and we didn't change anything since.
Could you please help me to found out what's the problem?
Thanks.

The first thing we did was restarting all the services and even rebooting the server, but it didn't help.
As I mentioned before we didn't change anything since we installed CDR and it worked fine then. We've checked all the settings and haven't found anything suspicious.

Comment: Did you read the ToolTip you get for the `asterisk` tag?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm comletely new here and I really need help. If I made my first post breaking some rules, I appologize for that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as per ther ToolTip, questions regarding Asterisk are off topic on this site

Comment: There are many posts about Asterisk on this site and people help each other there. I didn't even suppose my post was worse than the others...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think this is related to asterisk and not to mysql or apache !! So it will be better if you  remove unrelated tags and share your asterisk configuration.

Comment: @Pandemic some of your tags are unrelated !

Comment: @SelVazi You may be right but this is the beginning of the ToolTip `QUESTIONS REGARDING THE USE AND CONFIGURATION OF ASTERISK ARE OFF-TOPIC.` USE and CONFIGURATION

Comment: Removing the TAG is an interesting reaction! Now maybe you should remove the beginning of the question `We use Asterisk CDR`

Comment: Listen, what do you want? I came here to get some help, but instead of that we discuss my post itself. What do you want me to do with my post: delete it, edit it, rephrase?
Is it really not allowes to ask any questions about Asterisk here? I don't understand. I'm not good in English and possibly don't get you right if it's a sarcasm or not. What should I do to make this post good enough? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try and post this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your asterisk GUI. For FREEPBX(most used) you should select exact date to see early records.